# How to connect local Google Cloud SQL stub against MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

When I try to connect to a local **Google Cloud SQL** instance in **Unit Tests** using the **LocalRdbmsServiceTestConfig** it defaults to an **Hsql In-Memory DB**.

How can I reconfigure this to connect to my local **MySQL** instance instead?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit of code from dev_appserver.py that might get you on the right track:

```
from google.appengine.api import rdbms_mysqldb
from google.appengine import api
sys.modules['google.appengine.api.rdbms'] = rdbms_mysqldb
api.rdbms = rdbms_mysqldb
rdbms_mysqldb.SetConnectKwargs(host=mysql_host, port=mysql_port,
                               user=mysql_user, passwd=mysql_password,
                               unix_socket=mysql_socket)
```

Comment: question has java tag, your answer is python